# Need help working with SMMRY API

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api, smmry

I'm using http://smmry.com/api for a small project. I'm fairly new to AJAX and have trouble using it. Here's what I have so far:

```
var a = $.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'http://api.smmry.com/&SM_API_KEY=XXXXXXXX',
  headers: {'Authorization': '["Expect:"]'},
  data: {'SM_URL':'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human%E2%80%93computer_interaction'},
  contentType:'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
});

console.log(a);
```

The error I'm getting:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.smmry.com/&SM_API_KEY=XXXXXXXX. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I'm fairly sure it has something to do with headers. I have no idea what to do and would really appreciate it if someone could help me!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting has to do with CORS. The XMLHttpRequest sends a preflight request, which is not supported by the SMMRY API, and is something that needs to be enabled server side. What can you do instead?

You can talk to their API through a server, e.g. a simple Node server. 
You then send the XMLHttpRequest to your own server, where you do allow preflight request by allowing CORS (this is a simple line of code in a Node / Express server), and you forward the request to the SMMRY API and send the response back to your site. This process is called "proxying".